# how to define the URL path in html for a image

Tags: image, path, html

how can I define the URL path for a image in html.

I working in a server with spark and access the web page with a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

To add image in html and fetch the image to the display you need to use  tag:

```
<img scr="http:: or ftp:: url or ip address here to the image">
```

To add link to your image to what ever site or ip address:

```
<a href="http:: or https:: or ftp:: url here to the external site"><img></a>
```